# Fancy indexing calculation of adjacency matrix from adjacency list

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, numpy-ndarray, array-broadcasting

**Problem**:

I want to calculate at several times the adjacency matrix `A_ij` given the adjacency list `E_ij`, where `E_ij[t,i] = j` gives the edge from `i` to `j` at time `t`.

I can do it with the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

nTimes = 100
nParticles = 10
A_ij = np.full((nTimes, nParticles, nParticles), False)
E_ij = np.random.randint(0, 9, (100, 10))

for t in range(nTimes):
    for i in range(nParticles):
        A_ij[t, i, E_ij[t,i]] = True
```

**Question:**

How can I do it in a vectorized way, either with fancy indexing or using numpy functions such as `np.take_along_axis`?

---

**What I tried:**

I expected this to work:

```py
A_ij[:,np.arange(nParticles)[None,:,None], E_ij[:,None,np.arange(nParticles)]] = True
```

But it does not.

---

Related to: [Trying to convert adjacency list to adjacency matrix in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43571393/12131616)

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the setup/context. What is nTimes? You're simulating something? Your adjacency list, as it is, doesn't make sense because you can have something connected more than once.

Comment: @AndrewHolmgren Yeah, let's say in principle the adjacency matrix can have several connections for each `i` and `A_ij` is not necessary the same as `A_ji`. nTimes means I'm doing it for several times (my particular context is a simulation), but you could take it as an extra index that you may use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work:

```
import numpy as np

nTimes = 100
nParticles = 10
A_ij = np.full((nTimes, nParticles, nParticles), False)
E_ij = np.random.randint(0, 9, (100, 10))

np.put_along_axis(A_ij, E_ij[..., None], True, axis=2)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case it may help other people, I also found a way to do fancy indexing in this problem, but @Chrysophylaxs answer was faster and simpler (I guess I was confused with the indices and I could not think about it). I also add @Mercury answer for comparison.

**Code:**

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time


nTimes = 1000000
nParticles = 10
A_ij1 = np.full((nTimes, nParticles, nParticles), False)
A_ij2 = np.full((nTimes, nParticles, nParticles), False)
A_ij3 = np.full((nTimes, nParticles, nParticles), False)
A_ij4 = np.full((nTimes, nParticles, nParticles), False)


E_ij = np.random.randint(0, 9, (nTimes, 10))

start_time = time.time()
for t in range(nTimes):
    for i in range(nParticles):
        A_ij1[t, i, E_ij[t,i]] = True
print("Loop: %s s" % (time.time() - start_time))

        
start_time = time.time()
A_ij2[np.arange(nTimes)[:,None],np.arange(nParticles)[None,:], E_ij[np.arange(nTimes)[:,None],np.arange(nParticles)[None,:]]] = True
print("Fancy indexing: %s s" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
np.put_along_axis(A_ij3, E_ij[..., None], True, axis=2)
print("Put along axis: %s s" % (time.time() - start_time))

start_time = time.time()
i, j = np.mgrid[:nTimes, :nParticles]
A_ij4[i, j, E_ij] = True
print("mgrid: %s s" % (time.time() - start_time))


print(np.allclose(A_ij1, A_ij2))
print(np.allclose(A_ij1, A_ij3))
print(np.allclose(A_ij1, A_ij4))
```

**Output:**

```
Loop: 2.5006823539733887 s
Fancy indexing: 0.11996173858642578 s
Put along axis: 0.0814671516418457 s
mgrid: 0.19223332405090332 s
True
True
True
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do it, and close to what you actually tried at the end would be something like:

```
i, j = np.mgrid[:nTimes, :nParticles]
A_ij[i, j, E_ij] = True
```

But the accepted answer is definitely the better way to go about the problem, no need to construct indices.